# CSV - How to represent multiple values in one cell

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

I have to export data to a CSV file, but I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. One specific column of the CSV file need to hold multiple values, and each one of these values must have a date specified. Example:

```
1.50 happened on the 31/01/2021
1.45 happened on the 28/02/2021
1.56 happened on the 31/03/2021
1.55 happened on the 30/04/2021
```

Can I do the following?

```
Place;Performance;Name
Berlin;"31/01/2021 1.50" "28/02/2021 1.45" "31/03/2021 1.56" "30/04/2021 1.55";Andrew
```

Answer (score 0):

With the folowing you will get one cell in column 'Perfomance' with value:
"31/01/2021 1.50" "28/02/2021 1.45" "31/03/2021 1.56" "30/04/2021 1.55"

This will be interpreted as string/text.

You can try to desing specific output in Excel then save as CSV, and see with notepad how the csv looks like.